# Swagger(Swashbuckle) UI not loading from remote host

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have implemented Swagger (through Swashbuckle) ontop of a .NET Web API project, and it all works perfectly when running from localhost. However when I host via IIS on a remote machine, the UI is very slow to load (1 min +), and only loads the header, not the endpoints.

I have enabled CORS in IIS for the site, and added the following extension to the 'EnableSwagger' method;

```
c.RootUrl(req => req.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + req.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot.TrimEnd('/'));
```

I'm assuming there is some kind of path resolving issue, but am at a loss as to what it is. Any ideas?